# ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

I setup HBase on CYGWin on windows 8. When I run start-hbase.sh everything seems true: Zookeeper, region server and master start but when I want to see status in any browser by localHost:60010 I get Unable to connect and when I want to run any command like list I got this error: ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection0x0 Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
[image: ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries]
hbase-env.sh:

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_45/
    export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/hbase-1.0.1/lib/
    export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
    export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=$HOSTNAME
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/hbase/data</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/hbase/tmp</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
       </property>
     </configuration>
```

Try both default (point to windows hosts file) and this

```
     127.0.0.1       localhost
```

And test with disabling the ipv6 without any luck. I’m very new in HBase. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I would recommend you using the latest stable release 1.1. Did you follow these steps: http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html ?

Comment: i used this steps too. and use two version of hbase (94.27,1.0.1) and get this error but when i run other versions i get this error too : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform.